# Automatically update Google Apps Script webapp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google web app displaying an HTML dashboard with data pulled in via AJAX. The Spreadsheet is populated using a Google Form and I'd like the data (mock election results) to be updated every 10 seconds or so as votes come in so teachers can see live results.

Here's the relevant portion of the app:

**code.gs**

```
function getData() {
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  return JSON.stringify(data);
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile("index")
    .evaluate();
}
```

**HTML template**

```
      function popularVote(data) {
        var getDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("percent");
        var data = JSON.parse(data);

        for(var j=0;j<getDivs.length;j++) {
          getDivs[j].textContent = ((data[j][1]/data[j][2]) * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
        }
      }
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(popularVote).getData();

      <div class="card" id="popular">
          <div class="cand" id="cand1">
            <h2>Candidate:</h2><span class="percent">Loading...</span>
          </div>
          <div class="cand" id="cand2">
            <h2>Candidate:</h2><span class="percent">Loading...</span>
          </div>
          <div class="cand" id="cand3">
            <h2>Candidate:</h2><span class="percent">Loading...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

What I can't figure it out is what actually pulls the data. Is the the success handler polling the server? Or is it the client-side script? Where should I include `Utilities.sleep` or similar?

Comment: hey BTW how did you manage to indent your code in the google sciprts?? when I try to use tab when editing an HTML file it wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this line is getting the data from the spreadsheet:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(popularVote).getData();
```

You could try wrapping this line in setInterval so that it is called every ten seconds:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(popularVote).getData(); 
 }, 10000);
```

There also may be a Google Apps Script equivalent for setInterval.

Comment: `setTimeout` ran it once after 10 seconds, but that led me to `setInterval` which works great. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, duh on my part. I updated the answer to use setInterval instead.

Comment: setInterval works well, but isn't there a way to update the html page like real time?