# Page redirects to a blank link when using anchor tag to open a modal

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to open a modal window using the anchor tag. The modal window successfully opens. However, the page redirects to a random blank page upon opening the modal window. How do I fix this?

```js
//script for modal
var modal = document.getElementById("modalAdd");

var btn = document.getElementById("addMissing");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- anchor -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#modalAdd" id="addMissing"> Add </a>

<!-- modal div -->
<div id="modalAdd">

  <div id="modalAdd-content">
    <span class="close"> &times; </span>

    <p> Modal Content </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: don't use an anchor tag where you should use a `<button>` tag.

Comment: I saw a few example that uses anchor tag in showing modal windows. I'm trying to do the same. Is it really impossible to accomplish this using anchor tag?

Comment: anchor tags are for navigating to a new page or to a specific `id` within a page. You're using the wrong tool for the job. A button element is the correct element to fire a modal

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use `button` to open a modal, but here's solution for your issue:

```
btn.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // this will prevent default action
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although I will also keep in mind that the best practice for opening modals should be buttons.

Answer (score 0):

replace you href tag with  href="javascript:void(0)" and get the value through
 data-model