# A solution to dynamically update the option list by a column in google sheet

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the below form: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTGqZqLTAsOpSweMn0xgHP0sOJPsFg5ZShC1HqzVoDoNi5h5Y/exec

I'm trying to dynamically update the option list from a column in this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_LSdBkvw5Z6L4ZQP5qZccLEfekNVRCeKQRLLb9Vm4eM/edit#gid=285745421

I'm using The solution provided by "Ziganotschka" here:
[How to auto populate form options based on a column in the attached spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441308/how-to-auto-populate-form-options-based-on-a-column-in-the-attached-spreadsheet)

The code is not giving any errors, still for some reason it gives an empty list of options in the form

Thanks in advance

Code.gs

```
function createInnerHTML()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("CHOICES");
var namesValues = names.getRange(2, 2, names.getMaxRows() - 
1).getValues(); 
var InnerHTML = [];
for (var i=0;i<namesValues.length;i++){
  InnerHTML.push('<option value="OPTION '+(i+1)+'>' + namesValues[i][0]+ '</option>'); 
}; 
InnerHTML.join('');
return InnerHTML;
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="ss-q-title">JOINT
<span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span></div>

<? var innerHTML= createInnerHTML(); ?>  
<div>
<select name="JOINT" id="JOINT" aria-label="JOINT  " aria-required="true" required="">
<option value=""></option>
//HERE the inner HTML will be inserted
<?= innerHTML?>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

By printing scriplets you just add your HtmlStrings with options as text content (if you inspect the element in console, you will see that all the options are present). UPD: btw, TheMaster's solution is easier to implement.

**Solution**

One of the many possible solutions is to return the Array of option objects to template and loop through each one, forming tags dynamically:

*Server-side*

```
function createInnerHTML() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("CHOICES");
  var namesValues = names.getRange(2,2,names.getMaxRows()-1).getValues(); 
  var innerHTML = [];
  for (var i=0;i<namesValues.length;i++){
    innerHTML.push({value:'OPTION '+(i+1), text:namesValues[i][0]}); 
  };
  return innerHTML;
}
```

*Client-side*

Please, note that this sample omits `<div>` element and any other wrappers for clarity.

```
<? var innerHTML= createInnerHTML(); ?>  
<select name="JOINT" id="JOINT" aria-label="JOINT" aria-required="true" required="">
<option value=""></option>
<? innerHTML.forEach(function(option) { ?>
  <option value="<?= option.value ?>"><?= option.text ?></option>
<? }); ?>
</select>
```

**Additional modifications**

I would suggest switching from `getMaxRows()` to `getLastRow()` as your script returns 296 options, most of which are blank and only have values set due to rows being empty.

Comment: NP, glad we could help! Do take a look at TheMaster's solution - it is a quick and easy fix if you don't expect (untrusted) user input to be passed to such a scriplet. Btw, you should probably think of moving to asynchronous loading as well (see BP)

Comment: About "moving to asynchronous loading", would you please suggest a reference on how to do so. Thanks again Oleg

Comment: Hi Mahmoud! I refered to [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates) reference provided by TheMaster, but if you need more in-depth look, take a look at [client-server documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) official docs - loading `createInnerHTML()` like this is discouraged in apps script (although not prohibited, you are limiting yourself to one-time load only [it can be enough for the task at hand, ofc] whereas async loading could be reused)

Answer (score 2):

#### Issues/Solution:

- Using printing scriplets(`<?=>`) to append html instead of force-printing scriplets(`<?!=>`)
- Missing closing quotes(`"`) in each option's html

#### Snippet(s):

- Html:

  ```
  <?!= innerHTML?>
  ```
- Code.gs:

  ```
  InnerHTML.push('<option value="OPTION '+(i+1)+'">' + namesValues[i][0]+'</option>'); //Note added "
  ```

#### References:

- [Scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates)